# source_location is not a member of std

Tags: c++, header, include, std-source-location

I'm getting this error "`source_location is not a member of std`" in this simple program and I have no idea why. I'm trying to work with source location but cannot get the header included properly. I'm using Visual studio 2019 version 16.10.3 and [compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) says its been suppoted since 19.29 (16.10)*

```
#include <source_location>

int main() {
    std::source_location test;
}
```

Comment: This header file is only available in C++20. Are you sure you have configured for C++20?

Comment: @SergeyA I'm not exactly sure. Do you know how I can check if i have?

Comment: Works fine with `/std:c++latest` for me

Comment: Did you enable the `/std:c++latest` compiler flag?

Comment: Project -> Properties -> C++ Language Standard

Comment: @NathanOliver ^^

Comment: @Frank ^^^^^^^^

Comment: @SergeyA ^^^^^^